# How to export content starting with "$" without cell content transformation to a number?

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, datatables-1.10

When I am trying to export data like "$101" in cells, am getting just numbers (number format) in resulted excel document.

How to prevent excel from interpreting such data as numbers, but just make it show these values as text?

Comment: Am using https://datatables.net plug-in, just to inform, because the tag is not so obvious

Comment: This is one of Excels annoying "features", have not so much to do with programming or dataTables, it can be prevented via some settings in Excel itself. I *believe* you can prevent Excel from turning the above into numbers by transforming `"$101"` into `="$101"`, but not sure - does not use Excel, and it is not a solution to ruin the data anyway, IMHO.

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks, indeed, it is not impossible to prevent Excel from doing it's dirty transforms on your data, I've found a way to customize cell displaying format at least.

Comment: I looks great! I would really like to upvote, just think you need to provide the essential code in the answer.  It will certainly be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed ands discribed [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40038/bugreport-buttons-excel-currency-symbol-appearing-on-right) and [in the documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5#Built-in-styles), datatables allow to change display format for Excel cells,
there is [an example](http://live.datatables.net/sojarepe/1/edit).